# Pass parameters from html page to start() function in unity3D webplayer application

Tags: unity, javascript

I want to pass a parameter from web browser to Unity3D web player as soon as it is loaded. I know that, as soon as the web-player is loaded, the `start()` function is execute inside web-player. So I want to pass parameter from  web browser to this `start()` function.

Comment: Where exactly is the parameter coming from? The HTML code somewhere? HTML isn't going to "pass" anything, but perhaps Unity could retrieve it. If we know where you want to get it from, that would help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The documentation you need is here: http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/Manual/UnityWebPlayerandbrowsercommunication.html

If you are able to control when you call `Start()`, eg. because that object isn't immediately created, then you can use the `getUnity().SendMessage` route to send in the parameters from the web page.

Otherwise, you might want to embed an `Application.ExternalCall()` into your Start() function to call out to a Javascript function in the web page, which can return the parameters you need.

Answer (score 1):

This one was worked well. (then automatically read parameters from html page as soon as web-player is loaded, this method is good for read the URL parameters)

inside html->

```
function OnUnityReady()
{

    u.getUnity().SendMessage("GameObject", "myTest", GET.Use_id);
}
```

inside unity3D C# code ->

```
void Start()

{

Application.ExternalCall("OnUnityReady");

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would rather consider using Application.srcValue which is the path to the web player data file relative to the html file (Read Only). Then you can attach a "?" with a parameter string.